# How to read all style properties a browser supports

Tags: javascript, css

I made a simple Javascript routine that reports all the style properties present in a browser.

```js
var list = new Array();
var div = document.createElement('div');
for (var style in div.style) 
    list.push(style);
```

And it works. The results are in JavaScript format, so for instance `borderTopLeftRadius` means the CSS property `border-top-left-radius`, `MozAnimationTimingFunction` means `-moz-animation-timing-function` and so on.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/SawmJ/) where you can see it live.

(The list is flawed, by the way. For instance, in Firefox and IE, the list doesn't even contain `float`, but it does in Chrome. Firefox and IE have `cssFloat`. Oh well, I can live with that.)

So far, so good.
However, my goal is to have only a list of CSS property names. But the results also include entries that are not property names at all, like `getPropertyPriority` and `length`. And my question is, how can I filter these out? How to differentiate between these entries (some are Javascript functions, some are read-only properties) and the actual CSS property names?

Edit:
I don't mind about the properties that apply to SVG only; it's OK to keep those.

Also, while most of the offending ones can be filtered out by checking if the property has type 'string' as Mr_Green pointed out (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/SawmJ/10/)), there are still some entries in the list that are not CSS property names, such as `cssText` and `marks` (the latter only in some browsers). I want to filter those out as well, but haven't found a way to do so.

The W3C mentions a function called [`supports()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#the-css-interface) but I haven't been able to make that work. Can anybody find me an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, just because a browser has a property doesn't mean that it supports it.

Comment: @Keith I use a broad definition of the word "support", that is, properties that show up in the "inspect element" list. Even though I know that many elements don't do anything with many of the properties. Or did you mean something else? If so, Can you name an example?

Comment: This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SawmJ/2/) filters somewhat close or perfect? not sure because I don't know all the properties of css :D

Comment: Mr_green, your example has filtered 10 entries. I think more filteration would be needed. Somehow what amazes me is he number of styles CSS actually has and how few we really use

Comment: For example `'backface-visibility' in document.body.style` returns true in IE10, but it's not been implemented correctly. `position` is supported by every browser, but `position: fixed` breaks for older IEs and just about every mobile browser.

Comment: [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) maybe?

Comment: @Mr_Green Your update is very much a step in the right direction. Thank you! Not perfect though, as MarsOne says. Still looking.

Comment: @Yoshi Neither of these have anything to do with CSS styles, just with the Javascript language itself.

Comment: @MrLister The fiddle which I stated above is just not removing the `svg styling properties`. Here is the detailed [**list**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) (_consider pure svg properties only_)

Comment: @Mr_Green ah! it was a trap ;)

Comment: @MrLister Correct, though you asked why `getPropertyPriority` or `length` are listed in your result set. And the two methods I mentioned are the solution to this problem. Because that problem itself has nothing to do with styles but rather with how you're traversing the given object (`div.style`).

Comment: @Yoshi Sorry, I must be a bit dim. Can you post an example (preferable as an answer, because this comment thread is getting way too long) that shows how to filter out, for instance, `cssText` from the list of results, based on the fact that `cssText` is only a Javascript property and NOT a CSS property. I can't seem to find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your goal is to check whether a property is supported or not but

```
function isPropertySupported(property)
{
    return property in document.body.style;
}
```

can check whether a property is supported or not. I hope it helps. Correct me if I am wrong.

[Check whether a CSS property is supported or not](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/check-if-a-css-property-is-supported/)

**EDIT:**

Check this out [CSS Supports](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/#CSS-interface)

```
supports(DOMString property, DOMString value), returns boolean
supports(DOMString conditionText), returns boolean
```

When the `supports()` method is invoked with two arguments property and value, it must return true if property is a literal match for the name of a CSS property that the UA supports, and value would be successfully parsed as a supported value for that property. (Literal match means that no CSS escape processing is performed, and leading and trailing whitespace are not stripped, so any leading whitespace, trailing whitespace, or CSS escapes equivalent to the name of a property would cause the method to return false.) Otherwise, it must return false.

Comment: No, that is exactly my problem. That function returns true if you test, for instance, `"item"`. But `"item"` is not a CSS style property!

Comment: I can't seem to make the `supports()` function work. Do you know any examples?